# How to get max value key name from Key-Value Pair in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var input = [
    {
        'id': 21254516,
        'plotHealth': {
            'id': 102655,
            "high": 5.74,
            "medium": 23.9,
            "low": 74.0,
        }
    },
    {
        'id': 21254519,
        'plotHealth': {
            'id': 102660,
            'high': 24.83236994219653,
            'medium': 43.09826589595376,
            'low': 32.06936416184971,
        }
    }
]
```

> and my output should be like

```
var output = [
    {
        "id": 21254516,
        "high": 5.74,
        "medium": 23.9,
        "low": 74.0,
        "overAll": "low",
    },
    {
        "id": 21254519,
        'high': 24.83236994219653,
        'medium': 43.09826589595376,
        'low': 32.06936416184971,
        "overAll": "medium",
    }
]
```

> I want to get highest value among high, medium and low that in this example is : "overAll": "low" and "overAll": "medium"
>   How I can do that?
>
> Thanks

Comment: ain't both "overAll" supposed to be "medium"?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Stack Overflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: I did not had any idea how to solve this but I tried solving my own question by taking the hints from the others answer thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made `object destructuring` and stored the plotHealth object into variable called `plotHealth`.

Then max value has been calculated using normal `Math.max()` method.

The maximum value's key has been generated using

`Object.keys(plotHealth).find( key => plotHealth[key] === maxNum);`

Then the object was formed and pushed into output array.

```js
var input = [
  {
      'id': 21254516,
      'plotHealth': {
          'id': 102655,
          "high": 5.74,
          "medium": 23.9,
          "low": 74.0,
      }
  },
  {
      'id': 21254519,
      'plotHealth': {
          'id': 102660,
          'high': 24.83236994219653,
          'medium': 43.09826589595376,
          'low': 32.06936416184971,
      }
  }
]

let output = [];


input.forEach(element => {
  const plotHealth = {...element.plotHealth};
  const {high} = plotHealth;
  const {medium} = plotHealth;
  const {low} = plotHealth;
  const maxNum = Math.max(high,medium,low);
  const key = Object.keys(plotHealth).find( key => plotHealth[key] === maxNum);
  delete plotHealth.id;
  const outputData = plotHealth;
  outputData.id = element.id;
  outputData.overAll = key;
  output.push(outputData);
});

console.log('output ', output);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried solving my own question by taking the hints from the above answer thanks!

```
function overALL(input) {
    var tempArr = [];

    for (const key in input) {
        if (input.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          const element = input[key];
          tempArr.push({
            id:element.id,
            high: element.plotHealth.high,
            medium: element.plotHealth.medium,
            low: element.plotHealth.low,
            overAllHealth: getOverAllHealth(element.plotHealth)

          });
        }
    }
    return tempArr || null;
}

function getOverAllHealth(plotHealth){
    const plotHealthTemp = {
                high: plotHealth['high'],
                medium: plotHealth['medium'],
                low: plotHealth['low']
            };
            const overAllHealth = Object.keys(plotHealthTemp).reduce((a, b) => {
                return plotHealthTemp[a] > plotHealthTemp[b] ? a : b;
            });

    return overAllHealth ;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do as This Example :

```
var highVals = [];
var output = [
{
    "id": 21254516,
    "high": 5.74,
    "medium": 23.9,
    "low": 74.0,
    "overAll": "low",
},
{
    "id": 21254519,
    'high': 24.83236994219653,
    'medium': 43.09826589595376,
    'low': 32.06936416184971,
    "overAll": "medium",
 }
]
 output.map(item => {
 highVals.push(item.high)
 })
 console.log(Math.max(...highVals))
```

You can get Highest value for other **medium** , **low** with this way too.

check  the example below :

[image: Edit exciting-voice-yk7z6]

Answer (score -1):

```
var output = [];
var kw = ['high', 'medium', 'low'];

for(var i=0; i<input.length; i++){
  newObj = {};
  newObj['id'] = input[i]['id'];
  var thresWord = "";
  var thresValue = 0;

  for(var j=0; j<kw.length; j++){
    newObj[kw[j]] = input[i]['plotHealth'][kw[j]];
    if(thresValue<newObj[kw[j]]){
      thresValue = newObj[kw[j]];
      thresWord = kw[j];
    }
  }
  newObj['overAll'] = thresWord;
  output.push(newObj);
}

console.log(output);
```